# Android App crash because of firebase-auth (react-native)

Tags: java, android, firebase, react-native

My app start crash crashing without any changing please help just happen yesterday and I don't know why. I tried to changed the com.google.firebase.auth version but the still crashing.
Before Update version

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    //Google Maps Dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    // Firebase dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.3'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:16.0.1'
```

After Update version

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    // Firebase dependencies
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:19.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'

`
```

I still getting the same kind of errors I don't know what should I do next please help.

```
03-26 00:19:32.209 31879 31991 I ReactNativeJS: java.lang.RuntimeException: There was an error while initializing the connection to Google Play Services: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method isAtLeastR()Z in class Landroidx/core/os/BuildCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.core.os.BuildCompat' appears in /data/app/com.xxx.ppz-Fm8fsstcIfFkgTpdIx9egw==/base.apk)
03-26 00:19:32.209 31879 31991 I ReactNativeJS:     at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzam.zzc(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.3.0:33)
03-26 00:19:32.209 31879 31991 I ReactNativeJS:     at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzam.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.3.0:21)
03-26 00:19:32.209 31879 31991 I ReactNativeJS:     at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzam.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.3.0:10)
03-26 00:19:32.209 31879 31991 I ReactNativeJS:     at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzau.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.3.0:31)
03-26 00:19:32.209 31879 31991 I ReactNativeJS:     at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.3.0:158)
03-26 00:19:32.209 31879 31991 I ReactNativeJS:     at io.invertase.firebase.auth.RNFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(RNFirebaseAuth.java:789)
03-26 00:19:32.209 31879 31991 I ReactNativeJS:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-26 00:19:32.209 31879 31991 I ReactNativeJS:     at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
03-26 00:19:32.209 31879 31991 I ReactNativeJS:     at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:158)
03-26 00:19:32.209 31879 31991 I ReactNativeJS:     at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
03-26 00:19:32.209 31879 31991 I ReactNativeJS:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
03-26 00:19:32.209 31879 31991 I ReactNativeJS:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
03-26 00:19:32.209 31879 31991 I ReactNativeJS:     at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
03-26 00:19:32.209 31879 31991 I ReactNativeJS:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
03-26 00:19:32.209 31879 31991 I ReactNativeJS:     at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:232)
03-26 00:19:32.209 31879 31991 I ReactNativeJS:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Answer (score 1):

So I have found a solution just change

```
androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-beta01
```

to

```
androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-alpha03
```